# Using aws ec2 credentials for sftp access

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to sftp into an AWS EC2 instance.

I have:

- a credentials file (`credentials.csv`) containing my username, Access Key Id and Secret Access Key.
- a password that lets me log in to the AWS management console with the same username as in my credentials.

I do *not* have:

- a .pem file.

All the instructions I have seen explaining how to sftp in require a .pem file.

Is it possible to sftp in with just my credentials and password? Alternatively can I download a .pem file from the AWS management console, or otherwise configure my instance to permit access with the password and credentials that I do have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sftp in with just my credentials and password?

Nope. Your `.pem` file is *required*.

It is attached to your EC2 Key Pair. Whichever Key Pair you assigned to the instance is the `.pem` file you should use. If you've lost it, the only solution is to delete that Key Pair, create a new one, and keep track of the `.pem` file.

One of the fundamental tenets of using "The Cloud" is that servers are cheap and disposable, therefore, the server should never hold the canonical reference to your code or configuration. Deployments and server configuration should be automated. This *lose-your-key-pair-lose-your-instance* thing simply reinforces that (very important) tenet.

I don't recall off-hand if you can change the Key Pair of a running instance or not. If not, losing the server and replacing it with another one is expected to be completely trivial and non-impactful to your site or web app… if you're doing it right. :)